# Bash script to run if HTML has changed

Tags: html, bash, shell, curl

I write a .sh script that firstly downloads the source code of a page and secondly executes a Rscript **only if the source code downloaded is different from the latter**. The page is updated once a day and the URL ends with the actual date. This is all on a server and a cron job would run the .sh every 15 min. So I do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

lwp-download "https://geodes.santepubliquefrance.fr/GC_indic.php?lang=fr&prodhash=de1751e6&indic=type_hospit&dataset=covid_hosp_type&view=map2&filters=sexe=0,jour="$(date '+%Y-%M-%d') download.html
md5 page.html > last_md5
diff previous_md5 last_md5
if[ "$?" = "!" ] ; then
        Rscript myscript.R
fi
mv last_md5 previous_md5
rm page.html
```

First problem, it carries on running the R script even though *download.html* is downloaded and unchanged.
Plus, I hit an error after the R script has run `"Syntax error: "fi" unexpected"`

Comment: I suggest to replace `!` with `1`.

Comment: And put a space in `if[` making it `if [` - that explains the syntax error you get.

Comment: typo? `download.html` (downloaded) vs `page.html` (used for detecting a change)?

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Is your program calculating the `MD5` sum called `md5`? It's called `md5sum` on my machine, but I guess that can differ.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I put md5 in this script only because after having gathered many bits of code, one that displayed md5 seemed to work, though it may not be necessary to put that bit there. I'm not experienced enough to answer your question

Comment: @hug Try to give `echo -n | md5` as a command on the command line. Do you get `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` back or an error? If you get an error, try with `md5sum` instead.

Comment: indeed, echo -n | md5sum returns d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e whilst md5 return 'command not found'

Comment: @hug Aha, ok, then change to using `md5sum` in your bash script too.

Comment: Ok thanks again @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- You need to put a space between `if` and `[` - or you could just do `if command; then`.
- You calculate the MD5 sum on the wrong file.
- You remove the wrong file.

Since you're probably not interested in seeing the actual diff in the MD5 sums, I suggest that you use `cmp -s` instead of `diff`.

Also note that I quoted the `$(date ...)` command too. It's not necessary in this particular case, but it makes linters happy.

```
#!/bin/bash

lwp-download "https://geodes.santepubliquefrance.fr/GC_indic.php?lang=fr&prodhash=de1751e6&indic=type_hospit&dataset=covid_hosp_type&view=map2&filters=sexe=0,jour=$(date '+%Y-%M-%d')" download.html

md5 download.html > last_md5

if ! cmp -s previous_md5 last_md5; then
    Rscript myscript.R
    mv last_md5 previous_md5
else
    rm last_md5
fi

rm download.html
```

Comment: Thanks. Again, I'm not sure I sould've include md5 there. It seems to work though

Answer (score 0):

You should leave a space between if and [.

```
#!/bin/bash

lwp-download "https://geodes.santepubliquefrance.fr/GC_indic.php?lang=fr&prodhash=de1751e6&indic=type_hospit&dataset=covid_hosp_type&view=map2&filters=sexe=0,jour="$(date '+%Y-%M-%d') download.html
md5 page.html > last_md5
diff previous_md5 last_md5
if [[ "$?" = "!" ]] ; then
        Rscript myscript.R
fi
mv last_md5 previous_md5
rm page.html
```

Also i'd recommend if you dont see any error to use any online lint to guide you in whats wrong

https://www.shellcheck.net/